# GM .write not making file

Tags: node.js, gm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiQ91.png)
gm.write not making file

The path file in the write of gm does not work, and there is still no response even if the path is changed, and no error is reported。I want to find this problem, but gm didn't report an error, and resize() didn't work, I wrote it according to the official document

Comment: Remember to actually [read the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), because to quote them, including bold text and all caps: "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc** — copy or type the text into the question.*"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.